# Can we convert a Knapsack problem to Logarithmic time?

Tags: java, big-o, dynamic-programming

If I want an optimal solution that is guaranteed, then the best I can do is a N^(N-1) solution as I have to evaluate every possible combination.

If I want to find a good solution that is similar to optional, then I think there are algorithms in O(log(N)) to find such solutions. What is actually is the answer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Approximation_algorithms

Comment: By the way, "logarithmic time" would be O(log n), not O(n log n). Achieving a sensible approximation in O(log n) time is clearly impossible because you need to visit each item at least once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it, **It depends**, it depends to me, and to you, and to your system. The scope of such problems is surprisingly large, that is, the data storage capacity it requires. With respect to limiting dynamic programming, the challenge is the number of different sub-problems in the code that you fix. The challenge is always so high that there is no time limit. I will have to optimize it in the situation. The multiplication of the Matrix chain, for instance, is supposed to fall under that group.

Some scenario, I may use a matrix or a hash table, though; this is because both have time for O(1) lookup. The complexity of time can be increased from O(2^n) exponential time to O(2^n) psuedo-polynomial time complexity (N x W). It also means that if WW is a constant, or bounded by a polynomial in NN, my Knapsack power, the dynamic program is polynomial time.

But I need to optimize it from psuedo-polynomial time O(N x W) to logarithmic time complexities O(log n). For Example, I have a Knapsack Problem solved in Dynamic Programming approach which took polynomial time complexities O(N x W) in both space and time:

```java
class Knapsack { 
  
    static int max(int a, int b)  
    { return (a > b) ? a : b; } 
  
    static int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n) 
    { 
        int i, w; 
        int K[][] = new int[n + 1][W + 1]; 
  
        for (i = 0; i<= n; i++) { 
            for (w = 0; w<= W; w++) { 
                if (i == 0 || w == 0) 
                    K[i][w] = 0; 
                else if (wt[i - 1]<= w) 
                    K[i][w] = max(val[i - 1] + K[i - 1][w - wt[i - 1]], K[i - 1][w]); 
                else
                    K[i][w] = K[i - 1][w]; 
            } 
        } 
  
        return K[n][W]; 
    } 
  
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int val[] = new int[] { 60, 100, 120 }; 
        int wt[] = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 }; 
        int W = 50; 
        int n = val.length; 
        System.out.println(knapSack(W, wt, val, n)); 
    } 
}
```

But DP needs a lot of storage capacity in terms of practical constraints, and also easily extends with the vector space dimension.

Comment: I'm not aware why moving the solution to polynomial time is just using a hash table. To get the best solution, you do need to search all variations. I don't think you'll be able to get it,,

Comment: @kelly-jade, NP-Complete is the overarching knapsack problem, so there is no known precise algorithm that runs in polynomial time, even less logarithmic time. It depends on how you handle it thus. To minimize the computing space, much safer